# Can a Shudra/Mleccha become a Guru if he is self realised?

Tags: guru, varnashrama

Is a self realised shudra an exception to varna ashram dharma and can become guru?
Or can he simply become mentor?
And can he give any form of diksha to disciple?

Comment: You are mixing the caste or jati system with the varna system, A person who is self realised has gone beyond the varna system since he has gone beyond the three gunas. Such a person can not be called shudra.

Comment: See Chandogya Upanishad IV.4.4-5. The story of Satyakama.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will read

Comment: Shudra can become guru without any doubt. there are historic examples. But I'm not sure about Mlecha, especially if they had eaten cow meat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Pradip sir mentioned, anyone who knows Spiritual truth can bestow Knowledge. Ramanujacharya accepted Kanchipurna a Sudra as Guru. Nammalvar another Sudra wrote Divya Prabandham which is known as Tamil Veda. Dharmavyadha and Vidura were Sudras who bestowed knowledge even to Bramhins and Kings. These quotes proove that even a Sudra can be a Guru-

> Yajnavalkya says **By obtaining Brahmajnana** **from a** Brahmana or
> Kshatriya or Vaishya or **Shudra** or even a person of low caste,
> **person with faith should constantly practice the same**.(Mahabharata Shanti Parva 378,Shl 87)
>
> Whether one is a Brahmana, a Sannyasi **or a Sudra , regardless of
> what he is , he can become a spiritual master if he knows the science
> of Kṛṣṇa**.(CC Madhya 8.128)